# Required alt text field in assets

Tags: assets, matrix

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing this wrong. I have an asset volume called "Blog Images" and there is a custom required field called Image alt text. If I add images in assets section I'm required to put something in for the alt text, that's good because that what I intended. But I'm using a matrix block that has an asset field that looks to this volume and I am able to upload and image to this volume and not add anything in this field. What am I doing wrong?

Also I should mention this is using Craft 3.

Comment: I've been wondering this same thing! I can't even find a _way_ for editors to update alt text from the assets HUD.

Comment: having issue at the code side or at the control panel of craft cms?

Comment: You mean you are able to upload an image without entering text even though "alt text" it is a required field at this volume?
I think the required field only works as required once the picture is uploaded and you open it and want to save it again.

Answer (score 2):

This is available as of 3.2. Make the alt text field required for the asset volume, then check the "related element validation" box when creating an asset field.